# setTimeout only on first visit

Tags: javascript, local-storage, settimeout, show-hide, savechanges

I want to show my hidden div in 3 secs and after that, it will show even after the refresh, but the problem is when I reload the page I have to wait 3 secs again.

So I want to prevent the setTimeout function on page reload.

I tried localStorage to save my changes from style: display ="none" to style: display="block" but it seems like the setTimeout still working on page reload.

Please help I need to show my hidden div for 3 secs and after that no need to wait 3secs again and again on page reload. Here is my script

```
<body>
   <div id="img1" class="whatsapp" style="display: none;">
      <img src="https://pub-static.fotor.com/assets/projects/pages/d5bdd0513a0740a8a38752dbc32586d0/600w/fotor-03d1a91a0cec4542927f53c87e0599f6.jpg"/>
      <div class="whatsappbut">
        show me in 3 seconds and I will be here forever!
      </div>
   </div>
      
<script>
  var saveNow = localStorage.getItem('saveNow');
         
  if (!saveNow || saveNow == 'true') {
      setTimeout (function() {    
           document.getElementById("img1").style.display ='block';
           localStorage.setItem('saveNow', 'true');
      }, 1000 * 3);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: So you really want that this delay only happens the first time, and all the other times **in the rest of a user's lifetime** you don't want the delay? NB: properly indenting your code helps to see what it is doing.

Comment: When you debug, what is the runtime value of `saveNow`?

Comment: Change `saveNow == 'true'` to `saveNow !== 'true'`

Comment: If you want it to show it directly on all subsequent pages, then you either need to not use setTimeout on those then (but rather execute the code that shows the element directly), or us a little trick - and make the _delay_ of your setTimeout call 0 instead of 1000 * 3 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use hidden and I name the variables in an understandable manner.

Uncomment the localStorage calls when done testing. they do not work here at SO

Change `const showNow = null`  to `const showNow = 'true'` to see it work here

```html
<div id="whatsappDiv" class="whatsapp" hidden>
  <img src="https://pub-static.fotor.com/assets/projects/pages/d5bdd0513a0740a8a38752dbc32586d0/600w/fotor-03d1a91a0cec4542927f53c87e0599f6.jpg" />
  <div class="whatsappbut">
    show me in 3 seconds and I will be here forever!
  </div>
</div>
<script>
const showNow = null // localStorage.getItem('showNow');
const whatsapp = document.getElementById("whatsappDiv");
if (showNow) whatsappDiv.hidden = false;
else setTimeout(function() {
    whatsappDiv.hidden = false;
    // localStorage.setItem('showNow', 'true');
  }, 1000 * 3);
</script>
```

Comment: thank you so much ^^ it really works and you explained it very well <3 thanks again.